# Problem with mochawesome: TypeError: Cannot set property 'testsRegistered' of undefined

Tags: mocha.js, mochawesome

After running autotest instead of getting mochawesome report I get "Problem with mochawesome: TypeError: Cannot set property 'testsRegistered' of undefined"

I've tried to update to "mochawesome": "^4.1.0" and reinstall package but these didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to install mocha globally. That solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue with the same version of mochawesome. Except I'm using Mocha/Chai/Supertest.

It only happens when running my tests and setting an environment variable at run time via the command line. (e.g. env HOST=http://localhost:8080 mocha test/tests.js"), and it only happens to the very last test in the file, regardless of what that test is.

The only work around I have found is to set the environment via package.json instead of setting it at runtime via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and have been able to avoid it by changing my mocha version from 6.2.0 to 5.0.4. The problem for me is that moving version numbers backwards isn't an option.

Changing mochaawesome versions had no effect for me either